# FireDAC precedes query with DECLARE CURSOR

Tags: postgresql, firedac

When I execute following query in PG Admin III, it runs fine:

```
WITH new_values (updated_at,talker_id,sentence_id,v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) AS (
    VALUES (current_timestamp,'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
),
UPSERT AS (
    UPDATE utel u
    SET
        updated_at=nv.updated_at,
        v0=nv.v0,v1=nv.v1,v2=nv.v2,v3=nv.v3,v4=nv.v4,v5=nv.v5
    FROM
        new_values nv
    WHERE
        u.talker_id=nv.talker_id AND u.sentence_id=nv.sentence_id RETURNING u.*
)
INSERT into utel (updated_at,talker_id,sentence_id,v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
SELECT updated_at,talker_id,sentence_id,v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
FROM new_values WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM upsert up
    WHERE
        up.talker_id=new_values.talker_id
        AND up.sentence_id=new_values.sentence_id
)
```

but when I try to execute it through TFDQuery, PostgreSQL complains:

> syntax error at or near "INSERT" at character 355

I turned on PostgreSQL logging to Windows error log and saw following:

```
DECLARE "10STM" CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
WITH new_values (updated_at,talker_id,sentence_id,v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) AS (
    VALUES (current_timestamp,'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
),
UPSERT AS (
    UPDATE utel u
    SET
        updated_at=nv.updated_at,
        v0=nv.v0,v1=nv.v1,v2=nv.v2,v3=nv.v3,v4=nv.v4,v5=nv.v5
    FROM
        new_values nv
    WHERE
        u.talker_id=nv.talker_id AND u.sentence_id=nv.sentence_id RETURNING u.*
)
INSERT into utel (updated_at,talker_id,sentence_id,v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
SELECT updated_at,talker_id,sentence_id,v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
FROM new_values WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM upsert up
    WHERE
        up.talker_id=new_values.talker_id
        AND up.sentence_id=new_values.sentence_id
)
```

When I execute the same, with `DECLARE "10STM" CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR` in PG Admin III, I get exact the same error.

Why FireDAC precedes PG query with a cursor and how to avoid this?

Comment: Do you use `ckStatic` cursor kind (in your fetch options)? Do you use transactions? Which FireDAC component? Which version of Delphi? Have you considered executing this in a block? I can see what happens in Tokyo, just want to review what led to that decision.

Comment: @Victoria: Thank you very much. It was `ckAutomatic`. I changed it to `ckDefault` and it works now. Please, get your points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Victoria doesn't want to get her points, so here is the answer:

Cursor kind in fetch options was set to `ckAutomatic`. I changed it to `ckDefault` and it works now.